# Many "eth1: Link is Down" and "eth1: Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX" errors in /var/log/messages

Tags: networking

We have a Linux box running SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 (x86_64).

recently, we found many "Link is Down/Up" in /var/log/messages

and the Link was actually Disconnected and Reconnected many times,

this make this server almost unusable (ping test has a packet loss of 20%)

How can i address such an issues? any suggestion is welcome, thanks very much.

```
# lspci |grep -i eth
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)
04:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 80003ES2LAN Gigabit Ethernet Controller (Copper) (rev 01)

# uname -a
Linux mybox 2.6.27.19-5-default #1 SMP 2009-02-28 04:40:21 +0100 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

# ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
        Link detected: yes
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked your switch and ethernet cable, that is most likely the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, definitely sounds like a hardware error. It could be your NIC, your cable or the switch port. Easiest would be the swap the network port on the switch first, then swap the cable, then finally swap the NIC to isolate the issue.

Comment: I'd replace the cables first; otherwise you'll always have a switchport on the switch that you'll be suspicious of.

Answer (score 1):

Try turning autonegotiation off.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to disable NetworkManager completely. It was my case with 2 network cards and same behaviour. 
First look if it's running:

```
nmcli device status
```

and stop it:

```
systemctl stop NetworkManager
```

then, look if there it is a service still running:

```
systemctl list-unit-files | grep NetworkManager
```

and proceed to disable/stop it:

```
systemctl disable NetworkManager
```